# WidgetKit - Link with text and image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I am trying to create something like this:

[image]

This is what I've got so far:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "xxxx")!) {
    Text("Lock")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.caption)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(15)
}
```

My image:

[image]

But how do I add the lock image in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a system image

```
    HStack(spacing: 4){
        Image(systemName: "lock.open.fill")
        Text("Lock")
    }.foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.caption)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(15)
```